# How to diagnose clustering results

Tags: clustering

I am running clustering on text messages using different feature extraction approaches and algorithms.

Most of my data is unannotated but a small part of it annotated based on the type of message: "complaint", "greeting".

**My objective** is to use the annotated part of my data to determine the best approach for clustering the unannotated part of my data. To do this I cluster the annotated data and measure the clustering quality using the Adjusted Rand Score.

The average score I obtained was quite low: around 0.10 with K-Means and close to 0 with DBSCAN. Are there any good practices when it comes to diagnosing clustering outcomes?

Comment: Why do you want to cluster annotated data? How do you define "best approach"?

Comment: I have a big amount of unannotated data that I don't have resources to analyze manually. I wanted to test different feature extraction approaches, algorithms and similarity metrics on an annotated portion of my data in order to develop an intuition on the ones that would work best on the unannotated part of my data.

Comment: But that still doesn't seem to call for clustering. I think you want to test different methods of supervised learning on your annotated data and then apply the best ones to your unannotated data.

Comment: I have now clarified my question.